# Change TintColor of UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, uiappearance, tintcolor

I've set a global *tintColor* in my app by calling:

```
UIView.appearance().tintColor = myColor
```

However, the same color applies to the *UIImagePickerController* and only some of the UI elements are colored:
For example, the **sun** icon has a custom *tintColor* while the **focus frame** has the default one.

How is it possible not to apply a global appearance configuration to the `UIImagePickerController`?

[image]

My proposed solution doesn't fully address the issue, since the *inputAccessoryView* still has its own tintColor:

```
window?.tintColor = myColor
```

**Update:**

I configure the application-wide tintcolor on launch:

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    configureWindowAndInitialViewController()
    UIView.appearance().tintColor = .cyan // Setting a global tintColor
    return true
  }
```

Then, I show an *UIImagePickerController*:

```
  func presentPhotoPicker(sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType) {
    if let mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: sourceType)?
      .filter({$0 == kUTTypeImage as String}),
      !mediaTypes.isEmpty {
      let picker = UIImagePickerController()
      picker.delegate = self
      picker.mediaTypes = mediaTypes
      picker.sourceType = sourceType
      picker.allowsEditing = true
      controller?.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  }
```

**Input accessory view:**

To add an input accessory view, first of all, a *textField* should be created. Then it is possible to just attach a toolbar to the *Textfield*:

```
let spacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: sefl.view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing))
items.append(contentsOf: [spacer, doneButton])

toolbar.setItems(items, animated: false)
textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
```

[image]

Comment: What iOS version are you using? I tried on iOS 11.4, it works as expected

Comment: I was on iOS 11.3, I can test with Beta 12

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your result?

Comment: @trungduc just checked with the latest iOS 12 beta, the "Sun" or "Brightness icon is still colored incorrectly. Screenshot: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8013017/41587254-6a6c9aec-73b7-11e8-971a-05616e64d627.PNG

Comment: I set `tintColor` in `AppDelegate` an show `UIImagePickerController` from an `UIViewController`. This is screen shot https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhuHh.jpg. Button's color in `UIViewController` changes but everything inside `UIImagePickerController` is normal. Can you show how did you configure `UIImagePickerController`?

Comment: @trungduc please, share you code here. I'm curious to see it.

Comment: @trungduc I've updated the example

Comment: You can check it here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k7h4B2GjtGJFRBvlOBBVzsfkW-xLQF9L/view?usp=sharing. Button's color changes due to `tintColor` was changed and I use `.camera` source type.

Comment: @trungduc that works (please take a look at my answer), however this doesn't change the `inputAccessoryView`'s `tintColor`.

Comment: This doesn't change the inputAccessoryView's tintColor because inputAccessoryView isn't a subview of current window (they don't have same view’s hierarchy) so window's tintColor won't affect inputAccessoryView. You can change inputAccessoryView's tintColor after initializing to make it work.

Comment: @trungduc exactly. Is there any way to do the opposite - to change the tintColor of the `UIImagePickerController` - cause it is the only odd component.

Comment: No because `UIView.appearance().tintColor` will affect every view in every window. I think changing inputAccessoryView's tintColor is a possible solution

Comment: @trungduc it doesn't really solve the issue, since I'll have to manually color every window.

Comment: Still not possible to directly set the tint in 2021.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you change `window?.tintColor`, `inputAccessoryView.tintColor` isn't changed because `inputAccessoryView` isn't a subview of current window (they don't have same view’s hierarchy) so `window.tintColor` won't affect `inputAccessoryView`.

To resolve problem, I suggest to use `NotificationCenter` to observe and change `window.tintColor` each time a new `UIWindow` becomes visible. You can put the code inside `AppDelegate`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.windowDidBecomeVisible), name: .UIWindowDidBecomeVisible, object: nil)
  return true
}

@objc func windowDidBecomeVisible(notification: NSNotification) {
  // Each time an `UIWindow` becomes visible, change its |tintColor|
  let visibleWindow = notification.object as! UIWindow
  visibleWindow.tintColor = .red
}
```

If you want to change `tintColor` only for the `UIImagePickerController`, you need to change `tintColor` for every view which is displayed on `UIImagePickerController`.

1. Define an extension to change all subview's `tintColor`.

   ```
   extension UIView {
     func changeTintColor(color: UIColor) -> Void {
       for view in subviews{
         view.tintColor = color
         view.changeTintColor(color: color);
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Use `UINavigationControllerDelegate` to get `UIViewController` which is displayed on `UIImagePickerView`. Change view's `tintColor` inside this controller

   ```
   func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
     viewController.view.changeTintColor(color: .red)
   }
   ```
3. Don't forget to set `UIImagePickerController`'s `delegate` to `self`.

Comment: Interesting idea! Is there any way to change `tintColor` only for the `UIImagePickerController`?

Comment: @RichardTopchiy My solution changes the application-wide tintColor without affecting the UIImagePickerController UI elements as you expected. Is there any problem with it?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by setting the global tintColor on Window instead of the *UIAppearance* proxy:

```
window?.tintColor = myColor
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is what you are looking for try this and tweak to your likes:

```
let myImagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
myImagePicker.navigationBar.translucent = false
myImagePicker.navigationBar.barTintColor = .blueColor() // Background color
myImagePicker.navigationBar.tintColor = .whiteColor() // Cancel button ~ any UITabBarButton items
myImagePicker.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()
] // Title color
```

this is all I found:

**Customizing the Camera Controls**

```
var showsCameraControls: Bool
```

Indicates whether the image picker displays the default camera controls.

```
var cameraOverlayView: UIView?
```

The view to display on top of the default image picker interface.

```
var cameraViewTransform: CGAffineTransform
```

The transform to apply to the camera’s preview image.
Capturing Still Images or Movies

```
func takePicture()
```

Captures a still image using the camera.

```
func startVideoCapture()
```

Starts video capture using the camera specified by the UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice property.

```
func stopVideoCapture()
```

Stops video capture.

**Configuring the Camera to Use**

```
class func isCameraDeviceAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice)
```

Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a given camera is available.

```
var cameraDevice: UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice
```

The camera used by the image picker controller.

```
enum UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice
```

The camera to use for image or movie capture.
Configuring the Camera Capture Mode

```
class func availableCaptureModes(for: UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice)
```

Returns an array of NSNumber objects indicating the capture modes supported by a given camera device.

```
var cameraCaptureMode: UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureMode
```

The capture mode used by the camera.

```
enum UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureMode
```

The category of media for the camera to capture.

**Configuring the Flash Behavior**

```
class func isFlashAvailable(for: UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice)
```

Indicates whether a given camera has flash illumination capability.

```
var cameraFlashMode: UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashMode
```

The flash mode used by the active camera.

```
enum UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashMode
```

The flash mode to use with the active camera.

**Configuring the Export Presets**

```
var imageExportPreset: UIImagePickerControllerImageURLExportPreset
```

The preset to use when preparing images for export to your app.

```
enum UIImagePickerControllerImageURLExportPreset
```

Constants indicating how to export images to the client app.

```
var videoExportPreset: String
```

The preset to use when preparing video for export to your app.

I have dug thru the documentation and did not found a way of changing the focus view. Perhaps apple does not let you to do that. Maybe there is a custom PickerView framework on cocoapods or a custom camera framework.

Comment: Added some extra info hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, the problem is actually due to a bug in Apple's UIImagePickerController... So there is no "clean" way to update the TintColor across the whole app.

Comment: I suggest it would be a good idea to report it to them via the developers portal. So that they are aware of the issue and can fix it in the future.

Comment: Well you won't find out if you won't report it. Hope I was able to help a little bit at least.